# In “The One With The Flashback”, why is the Bar empty yet operational when Ross & Phoebe hang out?

Tags: friends

If you've watched the episode, Phoebe is at the bar and Ross arrives moments later, informing her of Susan being a lesbian. The entire bar since the start of this scene is empty! There's not even a bartender as Ross proceeds to make himself several drinks to drown his sorrow. What kind of a 'buffay' (buffet) bar is this? :P

Comment: This is explained *in the episode*, though. [Ross: Hi. Where is everybody? 
Phoebe: Oh, it’s already closed, Chris gave me the keys to lock up. *(presumably because she's a regular customer and he trusts her.)*] Maybe you watched a version with that scene missing?

Comment: Yes, that is it. The televised version broadcast didn't contain that scene :( Watched the ep online and it is as you say. Seems very risky to me though to hand keys to a woman alone in a bar (o_O) Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: OK, fair enough. Done!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, so it seems you watched an edited version of this episode. This is explained in [the uncut version](http://uncutfriendsepisodes.tripod.com/season3/306uncut.htm):

> *[Scene: the bar, Ross is entering, Phoebe is at the bar, they are the only two in the place.]*
>
> **Ross:** (all depressed) Hi. Where is everybody?
>
> **Phoebe:** Oh, it’s *already closed, Chris gave me the keys to lock up*-what is wrong?

It seems the guys frequent the bar so much that the owner or manager trusts them (plus Phoebe is very honest and friendly). And the bar was about to be closed down indefinitely anyway and turned into a coffee shop, so maybe he just didn't care anymore. ;)